# Google earth kml refresh causes placemark's description bubble to close

Tags: kml, google-earth

My KML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
    <Document>
      <NetworkLink>
        <Link>
          <href>http://localhost/test.php</href>
          <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode>
          <refreshInterval>1</refreshInterval>
        </Link>
      </NetworkLink>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Localhost/test.php returns:

```
<Document>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Testing</name>
    <description>
      Test
    </description>
    <Point>
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
      <coordinates>0,0,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</Document>
```

When you click on the icon, it opens the ballon that says "test", then after one second, when the kml is refreshed, the balloon closes, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have the balloon open, just add an `<open>1</open>` tag to the placemark

```
<Document>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Testing</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <description>
      Test
    </description>
    <Point>
      <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
      <coordinates>0,0,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
</Document>
```

However, this means the placemark will ALWAYS be open (balloon showing) when the link is refreshed.

If you want to refresh the kml and leave the balloon open or closed depending on it's current state, then you need to look into the [UPDATE](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#update) command instead, and use it to update only certain parts of the currently loaded KML, rather than replacing (reloading) the whole KML.

So it really comes down to, why are you Refreshing the KML in the first place??

EDIT: To answer question in comments

Use the `CHANGE` feature of the `UPDATE`

```
<Update> 
    <targetHref>http://www.domain.com/file.kml</targetHref> 
    <Change> 
      <Point targetId="point123"> 
        <coordinates>-95.48,40.43,0</coordinates>
      </Point> 
    </Change> 
  </Update>
```

That will change the coordinates of a placemark with an `id` of `point123` that was loaded in the kml mentioned as the `targetHref` (which was loaded via a `NetworkLink`)

Comment: I am plotting several objects on the earth that exist in real space, these need to be as accurate as possible, and updated often. Can I update the position of these without changing the description?

Comment: It is hard to help any more without further code from you. Make sure your .kml file is loaded via a NetworkLink. Make sure the targethref points to it correctly. Make sure you assign each Placemark and id and then the UPDATE feature works as documented.

Comment: I got it working, my problem was "targetID=" instead of "targetId=" uggghh thank you.